# Python formating script works on OSX but fail on windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, powershell

So I got a script who formats files issued from a server powershell command into a tabbed separated text file and when I run it on the same test.txt file everything goes well on OSx but when I try to run it on windows server it output an empty misnamed file. I get no error whatsoever but it clearly doesn't work the same on both OS.
Here's the script:

```
from sys import argv
import time
import datetime

script, filename = argv

optionNames = ['Client ID', 'User Name', 'Computer Name', 'Ext Privilege', 'IP Address', 'MAC Address', 'Connect Time', 'Duration', 'App Version', 'App Language', 'User Connections', 'License', 'File Name', 'Account Name', 'Privilege Set']

nbOptions = len(optionNames)
optionsFirstCharIndex = []
myFile = open(filename)
myText = myFile.readlines()


#print myText (debug)
for i in range(0,nbOptions):
    optionsFirstCharIndex.append(myText[0].find(optionNames[i]))

charIndexSize = len(optionsFirstCharIndex) - 1
storableOptionsLines = []
#store each as list item
for n in range(0,len(myText)):
    storableOptions = []
    for i in range(0,charIndexSize+1):
        if i != charIndexSize:
            j = optionsFirstCharIndex[i]
            k = optionsFirstCharIndex[i+1]
            storableOptions.append(myText[n][j:k].rstrip())
        else:
            j = optionsFirstCharIndex[-1]
            storableOptions.append(myText[n][j:].rstrip())
    storableOptionsLines.append(storableOptions)

outputText = ""
# formating the text 
for line in storableOptionsLines:
    for word in line:
        outputText += word + "\t"
    outputText += "\n"
s = time.time()
tStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s).strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M")

with open("report_" + tStamp + ".txt", 'w') as myOutputFile:
    myOutputFile.write(outputText)
myOutputFile.close()
```

When I use the print meant to debug I get indeed a list containing each row in the source file on OSx but in windows I get a super long list with lots of x00, x00U, x00F etc. The last letter seems to be a letter of each word.
\xfeC\x00l\x00i\x00e\x00n\x00t stands for client. Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?
Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using the same Python versions on each machine?

Comment: Your file content is in a multibyte encoding and your Python script on Windows is trying to read it as ASCII. This means things like `myText[0].find(optionNames[i])` won't find the option name because `Client ID` doesn't match with `C l i e n t I D` and with `len(optionsFirstCharIndex) --> 0` your loops won't do anything. You need to find out what the file encoding is, and decode it in your Python script. Could the Windows/MacOS difference be Python 2.x vs Python 3.x ?

Comment: I use python 2.7 on each machine. Thanks for the tip I'll look into it!

Comment: I figured it out on windows I had to use `| out-file report.txt -encoding default` instead of > to force the output to ANSI and the reason my file was misnamed and empty was pretty simple, you can't use ":" in files name and while osx replace it with "/" on windows it generates an error. Thanks for the help